# Given a PNG Blob object, how can I send the image to an external service like Google Drive?

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, png, blob

I have a Javascript Blob of a PNG image, that I created by writing my image to the canvas.

I know I can download the image using `window.saveAs(blob, name);`, but I would like to send the image to a server, specifically Google Drive (but the answer may be general).

I have tried

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.addEventListener("loadend", function() {
  var string = reader.result;
  // save string as a file to Google Drive with a .png filename 
  // and mimetype image/png
});
reader.readAsBinaryString(pngObject);
```

my request payload to Google Drive looks like

```
Request URL:https://content.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=multipart
Request Method:POST
Request Payload:

---------314159265358979323846
Content-Type: application/json

{"title":"my-file.png","mimeType":"image/png","parents":[{"id":"root"}]}
---------314159265358979323846
Content-Type: image/png

PNG

IHDR,Q; IDATx^íçsT×Å·rÎ#rÎDÎc 6öxjjÞ§ùWæÃTM½1lá1 @, [...etc]
```

However, the file is not visible as an image in Google Drive, nor on my computer after I download it.

When I download it from Drive and open up the "image" in vim, the results do look similar to other, working pngs I have:

```
<89>PNG^M
^Z
^@^@^@^MIHDR^@^@^A,^@^@^A^S^H^F^@^@^@<8c>Q;^M^@^@ ^@IDATx^í<9d>

[....]

^BÞ^Pø?gc<95>ô~2ÖÊ^@^@^@^@IEND®B`<82>
~                                                                               
~
```

But clearly there's something preventing it from being understood as a png.

Thoughts on how I should correctly write out my image file?

Comment: You may want to check on how you are passing the data to the request. Following this tutorial about [How to upload, update and save an image file to Google Drive using Javascript](http://dominoc925.blogspot.com/2014/02/how-to-upload-update-and-save-image.html). In this tutorial, they explain how to load an image file from a local drive, write some text on the image, then save the edited image to Google Drive in the cloud. Hope it helps!

Comment: Ah, I hadn't found that, but it looks the same as my solution below -- they write it out as base64, and set the `'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64'` line in the payload. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My solution ended up being to send the image encoded as base64, and to add a `Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64` to the payload.

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.addEventListener("loadend", function() {
  var data = reader.result.split(",").pop();  // get rid of base64 header
  // save data to Google Drive
});
reader.readAsDataURL(pngObject);
```

The payload to Google Drive looked like:

```
---------314159265358979323846
Content-Type: application/json

{"title":"my-file.png","mimeType":"image/png","parents":[{"id":"root"}]}
---------314159265358979323846
Content-Type: image/png
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAASwAAAETCAYAAACMUTsNAAAgAElEQVR4Xu2dh3dU
[...etc]
---------314159265358979323846
```

Comment: You probably had this issue because you didn't remove the other part of the string that needed to go. Here's Regex to peel off both parts for anyone interested.


`let matches = dataString.match(/^data:([A-Za-z-+\/]+);base64,(.+)$/);`